# What is inside an empty index of a Hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap that is 101 keys in size, but I know for sure about 6 of those have no data inside, and there may be more without data as well. What exactly is inside the empty indexes? Is it null? or is there a Hash(index).isEmpty() method that I can use to see if its empty?

I realize there is a isEmpty method inside hashmap, but I thought that only checked if the entire map was empty not just a single index.

Comment: can you use a debugger to inspect these "empty" elements?  I am still unclear about what you are asking.

Comment: [`Map.containsKey(key)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29)?

Comment: If your question is about how class `HashMap` works internally: you can lookup the source code in `src.zip` that's in your JDK installation directory.

Comment: The question was basically if you create a hashmap for example with size 10, but you only put 4 objects into it. If you are running a loop to check through your hashmap where those 4 objects were mapped to how would you go about checking which keys were empty and which keys had data inside since the isEmpty method only works for the whole map not specific keys. I figured out how to work through it earlier, but it was something that I was struggling with for a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the keys to arrive there with no data, you have to `put` them there.

If you did `map.put(key, null)` then yes the data for that key is `null`. You always have to give the second parameter to the method, you can't just `map.put(key)`.

If you know for sure that a certain key should have no data you could try going into debug mode and putting a watch for `myMap.get(myEmptyKey)` and see what you get (in case that no data is an empty object or something else, you should be able to see that).

Edit: Some code would be useful to help you, but if I understand correctly you do something like this:

```
for (Object obj : list) {
    if (matchesCriteriaX(obj)) {
         map.put("X", obj);
    else if (matchesCriteriaY(obj)) {
         map.put("Y", obj);
    }
}
```

Well, if you do that and try to do `map.get("X")`, but you never actually put anything for that key (becaus no object matched criteria X), you will most definitely get back a `null`.

On the other hand, if you did something like

```
Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
map.add("X", new ArrayList<Object>());
map.add("Y", new ArrayList<Object>());
for (Object obj : list) {
    if (matchesCriteriaX(obj)) {
         List<Object> list = map.get("X");
         list.add(obj);
    else if (matchesCriteriaY(obj)) {
         List<Object> list = map.get("Y");
         list.add(obj);
    }
}
```

then you could check if a category is empty by doing `map.get("x").isEmpty()` since List has that method (and it would be empty if no object matched the key criteria).

Comment: Well basically, my application is reading in 3300 products from a database and then mapping them based on certain criteria to different keys in the hash, so I know a few will be empty, but since I am using external hashing I know a couple of the keys will be empty due to not all the criteria being met.

So while I am running a loop to add all these into my tree I am trying to figure out how to skip the empty keys and move on to the next one.

Comment: "A couple of keys will be empty", what does that mean?  Does that mean these keys have no associated values, if so, then how did you add them in the hashmap in the first place?

Comment: Yes your basic first example was the short version of what I was doing. Got it all working, thanks for the help.

Comment: @SomeoneRandom: Instead of using `Map<String, List<Object>>` you can also use [`Multimap<String, Object>`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from the Google Collections Framework (now part of the [Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)).

Answer (score 1):

> I realize there is a isEmpty method
>   inside hashmap, but I thought that
>   only checked if the entire map was
>   empty not just a single index.

I think what you're looking for is the [`containsKey(Object)` method](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29). According to the documentation:

> Returns `true` if this map contains a
>   mapping for the specified key. More
>   formally, returns `true` if and only if
>   this map contains a mapping for a key
>   `k` such that `(key==null ? k==null :
>   key.equals(k))`. (There can be at most
>   one such mapping.)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `key` - key whose presence in this map is to be tested
>
> **Returns:**
>
> `true` if this map contains a mapping for the specified key

Answer (score 0):

Judging from what you said, I'm suspecting something like this:

```
Map<SomeKey, List<SomeValue>> yourMap;
```

If this is the case, what you can do is

```
if( yourMap.contains(someKey) ){
    List<SomeValue> someList = yourMap.get(someKey);
    if(someList.size() == 0){
        // it's empty, do something?
    }
}
```